# jQuery - get values from table row based on another table row index

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have 2 tables. One holds only first column of my "data table" rest is stored in another table, that is placed right to first.

What I need to do is to get all the data from specific row to pass it to jqplot.

My tables look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/eajpy/

My code basically works, but I think it can be improved.
Any advice will be helpful :)

My code looks like this:

```
$('table#baseTable  > tbody > tr > td'').click(function() {
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    $('div#log').html(rowIndex);

    var myData = [];

    $('#dataTable tbody tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ')').map(function() {
            return $(this.cells).get();
        }).each(function() {
    var headerVal = $(this).closest("table").find("thead > tr > th").eq($(this).index()).html();
    myData.push([headerVal, $(this).html()]);
})

    alert(myData);
    console.log(myData);
});​
```

Comment: This line: `var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());` can be simplified to `var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();`. However, code review questions are off-topic for SO. You should post over on [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Didn't know about that site :P I'll post my question there then and check Your solution.